# How to stop execution until a setState in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, logout

Recently have created a logout function. By which when user clicks on logout, they will be prompted a dialog asking "Are you sure that you want to logout ? ". For Dialog , I used a package named [react-native-popup-dialog](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-popup-dialog).

Actually, whats happening is as this app is clubbed with redux. I used action for logout functionality. And for dialog , i have used component level state.

My Dialog Code:

```
<Dialog
    visible={this.state.showDialog}
    dialogTitle={
    <DialogTitle 
    title="Confirm Logging Out"
    textStyle={{ fontSize: 15 }} 
    />}
    width={0.8}
    footer={
        <DialogFooter>
          <DialogButton
            text="CANCEL"
            textStyle={{ fontSize: 14 }}
            onPress={() => {
              this.setState({ showDialog: false });
            }}
          />
          <DialogButton
            text="CONFIRM"
            textStyle={{ fontSize: 14 }}
            onPress={() => {
                this.onLogoutPress();
            }}
          />
        </DialogFooter>
      }
    onTouchOutside={() => {
    this.setState({ showDialog: false });
    }}
>
    <DialogContent>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 14, top: 10 }}>Are you sure you want to logout ?</Text>
    </DialogContent>
</Dialog>
```

And my Logout Button Code:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> this.setState({ showDialog: true})} >
  <CardItem>
    <Icon name="log-out" style={{ color: '#03A9F4' }} />
    <Body>
      <Text>Logout</Text>
    </Body>
    <Right>
      <Icon name="arrow-forward" />
    </Right>
  </CardItem>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

So my `onLogoutPress()` code:

```
onLogoutPress() {
this.setState({ showDialog: false },() => {
    this.props.logOut(() => {
        this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetActionToWelcome);
    })
})
```

}

The issue I am facing is that, when I click on confirm button the `"onLogoutPress()"` shoots up, and the dialog is not closing instead of that the resetAction of react navigation shoots up.  As setstate is async function I think it took time to get back, within that the logout action is shoots up and app gets start from splash screen. But till the dialog is kept open.

How to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

change you function like below,

hope it will work for you
first ways,

```
onLogoutPress() {
   this.setState({ showDialog: false },() => {
   setTimeout(() => {
     this.props.logOut(() => {
           this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetActionToWelcome);
      })
      }, 500);

   })
}
```

another way using arrow function,

```
onLogoutPress = () => {
   this.setState({ showDialog: false },() => {
     this.props.logOut(() => {
           this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetActionToWelcome);
      })
   })
}
```

Comment: actually, its an workaround right ? But whats the actual way to face this issue ?

Comment: yes, your way is right but i don't know why it's not working so i suggest my ways

Comment: setState is async function and it wait until not set the state using arrow function

Comment: Couldnt get you ?

Comment: Ya first one is working, but i think this is not a clean approach ?

Comment: yes, may be but soon i will get back to right way if possible

and yes accept this one if your issue resolve for now :)